# Populate Variable in XSLT with value based on conditional check in other segment

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml with repeating DPART segment and need to pick ADDRESS value from any segment having PARTN_ROLE as 'UU' and use this address to get variables of NAME and STREET from other repeatable segment DCOAD.
so need to extract 2 variables:-

```
<xsl:variable name="Cust_Name"
<xsl:variable name="Cust_Street"
```

.

Output variable should be like:-

```
<Cust_Name>Michael</Cust_Name>
<Cust_Street>ABCH</Cust_Street>
```

Part of Input XML:-

```
<Z1E1P SEGMENT="1">
    <ORDER>5467899</ORDER>
    <ACCOUNT>X</ACCOUNT>
    <Z1BP_ISAORDER SEGMENT="1">         
       <DPART SEGMENT="1">
        <PARTN_ROLE>JK</PARTN_ROLE>
        <CONTACT>0000000000</CONTACT>
        <ADDRESS>0000027647</ADDRESS>
       </DPART>
       <DPART SEGMENT="1">
        <PARTN_ROLE>UU</PARTN_ROLE>
        <CONTACT>0000000000</CONTACT>
        <ADDRESS>9164412232</ADDRESS>
       </DPART>
       <DCOAD SEGMENT="1">
        <ADDRESS>0000023378</ADDRESS>
        <NAME>John</NAME>
        <STREET>gyhu</STREET>
        <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
       </DCOAD>
       <DCOAD SEGMENT="1">
        <ADDRESS>9164412232</ADDRESS>
        <NAME>Michael</NAME>
        <STREET>ABCH</STREET>
        <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
       </DCOAD>
    </Z1BP_ISAORDER>
</Z1E1P>
```

It needs to be handled using XSLT 1.0
I tried below XSLT but not getting the output, part of xslt:-

```
<xsl:variable name="Cust_Name">
    <xsl:if test="node()/Z1BP_ISAORDER/DPART[PARTN_ROLE='UU']/ADDRESS = node()/Z1BP_ISAORDER/DCOAD/ADDRESS">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()/Z1BP_ISAORDER/DCOAD/NAME">
        </xsl:copy-of>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="Cust_Street">
    <xsl:if test="node()/Z1BP_ISAORDER/DPART[PARTN_ROLE='UU']/ADDRESS = node()/Z1BP_ISAORDER/DCOAD/ADDRESS">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()/Z1BP_ISAORDER/DCOAD/STREET">
        </xsl:copy-of>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear in what context you declare the variables. But I suppose this will give you a good start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:variable name="allSegments"  select="/Z1E1P/Z1BP_ISAORDER/*"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="addressNumber"  select="$allSegments[PARTN_ROLE='UU']/ADDRESS/text()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="segmentToUse"   select="$allSegments[not(PARTN_ROLE='UU') and ADDRESS/text()=$addressNumber]"/>
      
  <xsl:variable name="Cust_Name"      select="$segmentToUse/NAME"/>
  <xsl:variable name="Cust_Street"    select="$segmentToUse/STREET"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$Cust_Name"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$Cust_Street"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will output:

```
<NAME>Michael</NAME>
<STREET>ABCH</STREET>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (which is not at all certain), you want to lookup the customer name and store based on matching `ADDRESS` value. This is best done by defining a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) and using it. Here is an example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="cust-by-addr" match="DCOAD" use="ADDRESS" />

<xsl:template match="Z1E1P">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="Z1BP_ISAORDER/DPART[PARTN_ROLE='UU']">
            <xsl:variable name="addr" select="key('cust-by-addr', ADDRESS)" />
            <Customer>
                <Cust_Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$addr/NAME" />
                </Cust_Name>
                <Cust_Street>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$addr/STREET" />
                </Cust_Street>
            </Customer>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <Customer>
    <Cust_Name>Michael</Cust_Name>
    <Cust_Street>ABCH</Cust_Street>
  </Customer>
</output>
```

---

Not sure what variables have to do with this. You cannot output a variable. You can only use it for temporary storage. Here I used a variable only to avoid repeating the same lookup twice.